# addClass doesn't work when element has an interpolation operator in class attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the addClass function within the angular.js `link` function and I think I found a bug.

**The problem:**

If I have an interpolation operator (`{{}}`) within the `class` attribute of the template, then `addClass` will fail silently and not add the new class.

For example -

Considering this link function:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('afterRepeat', function() {
    return  {        
        link: function(scope,element, attrs){                                                
                if (scope.$index%2==0){
                    element.addClass("special");
                }
            }
    }
});
```

**This template works and adds the class properly**

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" after-repeat>item {{$index}}</div>
```

**This template doesn't**

```
<div class="item{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in items" after-repeat>item {{$index}}</div>
```

**Here's a [jsFiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/CRyZh/)**

I think this happens because the attribute value gets evaluated after the link function - but that doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the link function be the last step in the chain?

Does anyone have an idea on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

a) Have a method on scope which will return the appropriate class names

```
$scope.getClass = function(index){
  var klass = 'item' + index;
  if(index % 2 === 0){
    klass += ' special';
  }
  return klass;
};

<div ng-class="getClass($index)" ng-repeat="item in items">item {{$index}}</div>
```

b) Make use of ng-class expression:

```
<div 
  class="{{'item'+$index}}" 
  ng-class="{special: $index%2==0}" 
  ng-repeat="item in items"
>
  item {{$index}}
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDJyw/)